# Python Tkinter OpenCV PIL image resize to fit label

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize my webcam output to fit into the label but I couldn't really make it work. If you decided to try and test the code I have put a blue background in the label as a guide on how large you will need to resize the webcam output.

The code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

isrunning = 0

def start():
    global isrunning
    if isrunning == 0:
        global cap
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        isrunning = 1
        lmain.grid(row = 1,column = 1)
        def show_frame():
            _, frame = cap.read()
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            lmain.imgtk = imgtk
            lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
            if isrunning == 1:
                lmain.after(10, show_frame)
    show_frame()

def Stop():
    global isrunning
    isrunning = 0
    lmain.grid_forget()

def main():
    Stop()
    Reset.invoke()
    stopFunc.invoke()

root = Tk()
lmain = Label(root, width = 800, height = 600, bg = "blue")
stopFunc = Button(root, text = "stop", command = Stop)
Reset = Button(root, text = "Reset", command = start)
Main = Button(root, text = "Stop", command = main)
Start = Button(root, text = "Start", command = start)
Start.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Main.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I tried resizing the webcam output to be the same as the size of the label

Comment: Resizing the webcam output is the goal, not what you've tried. I don't see anything in your code that seems to relate to image resizing. "Here's my code, fix it" is not a great way to ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code, and I change some code here:

```
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

isrunning = 0

def start():
    global isrunning
    if isrunning == 0:
        global cap
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        isrunning = 1
        lmain.grid(row = 1,column = 1)
        def show_frame():
            _, frame = cap.read()
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800,600)) 
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            lmain.imgtk = imgtk
            lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
            if isrunning == 1:
                lmain.after(10, show_frame)
            else:
                cap.release()
    show_frame()

def Stop():
    global isrunning
    isrunning = 0
    lmain.grid_forget()

def main():
    Stop()
    #Reset.invoke()
    #stopFunc.invoke()

root = Tk()
lmain = Label(root, width = 800, height = 600, bg = "blue")
stopFunc = Button(root, text = "stop", command = Stop)
Reset = Button(root, text = "Reset", command = start)
Main = Button(root, text = "Stop", command = main)
Start = Button(root, text = "Start", command = start)
Start.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Main.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, I add one line: `frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800,600))` to re-size the image.

And I found that after I add this line, here was an error occurred when I pressed the "Stop" button. So I try to use the `cap.release()` to release the camera every time when you pressed the "Stop" button. But I don't have webcam to test this code now, I can not ensure it will work when you re-start the stream. Hope it helps.

Comment: It did get the of the label but you can't restart it I'll tweak it a bit and I'll post the result

Comment: It works nicely if you uncomment the two lines of code

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think you can use the method you used before to stop the stream, although here will be an error occurred when users stop the stream. I think it should not affect the result, anyway.

Comment: no it's working fine, I could restart it without an error, I just ignored the error messages as long as the code works